# JACL Script for Topic Connection Factory getting errors

Tags: ibm-was, jacl

For the below lines i am getting error-

My lines for creating topic connection factory:

```
set aMQJMSProvider [$AdminConfig getid "/JMSProvider:Default messaging provider/"]
set aMQTopicCF [$AdminConfig getid "/Node:vistaNode/MQTopicConnectionFactory:vistaCCTopicFactory/"]

set nameAttr [list name vistaCCTopicFactory]

set jndiAttr [list jndiName jms/vista/vistaCCTopicFactory]]

set mappingModuleAttr [list mapping [list [list authDataAlias vistaNode/DefaultSSLSettings] [list mappingConfigAlias DefaultPrincipalMapping]]]

set attrs [list $nameAttr $jndiAttr $mappingModuleAttr]

set aMQTopicCF [$AdminConfig create MQTopicConnectionFactory $aMQJMSProvider $attrs]
```

Error:

**[exec] com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: WASX7444E: Invalid parameter value "" for parameter "parent config id" on command "create"**

[exec] while executing

```
[exec] "$AdminConfig create MQTopicConnectionFactory $aMQJMSProvider $attrs"

[exec] invoked from within

[exec] "set aMQTopicCF [$AdminConfig create MQTopicConnectionFactory $aMQJMSProvider $attrs]"

[exec]     (file "C:/proj/deploy/vista/application.jacl" line 112)

[exec]     (file line 112)

[exec]     invoked from within

[exec] "source $APPLICATION_DEPLOY_SOURCE/application.jacl"

[exec] Loading of application failed. Please make sure application.jacl exists and syntax is correct.

[exec] A failure occurred while installing the application onto the Deployment Manager.

[exec] Return code = 1

[exec] WASX7341W: No "save" was performed before the interactive scripting session exited; configuration changes will not be saved.
```

I have tried all the IBM links in which steps to create TCF are mentioned, and i am doing the same but not able to solve. Please provide valuable comments to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.
Deepal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message suggests that

```
$AdminConfig getid "/JMSProvider:Default messaging provider/"
```

within your first line, is returning an empty string.
Does a JMSProvider with name "Default messaging provider" exist within your configuration?

Comment: Yeahh ! I have Default Messaging Provider available, as its Default so i guess every WAS profile having this Default Messaging Provider. This is as per my understanding, if you think this is only the reason could you please let me know what exactly i have to check ?

Comment: Based on the fact that I can do $AdminConfig list 'JMSProvider' and "Default messaging provider" doesn't show up even though I can see it in the admin console, it might be intentional that getid won't give you a config id for it that you can use in these commands.  Have you tried createSIBJMSConnectionFactory with -type topic?
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/was_beta/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rjn_jmscf_create.html

Comment: Thanks using createSIBJMSConnectionFactory command i am able to configure required things but facing issue with setting Scope of the Topic Connection Factory. Could you please suggest for this ?